# WCF Service - Sending long data using localhost IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure, iis

I have a WCF which is used by both web application(C#.NET) and mobile app as below.

```
[OperationContract]

[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = 
@"createEmp?EMPId={EMPId}&empNONo={empNo}&subXML= {subXML}&Comments=
{Comments}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Employee createEmp(int EMPId, string empNo, string subXML, string    
Comments);
```

XML data which I am sending has long data.

And is working fine when I have published the service to azure but service is not being called when I publish the service to IIS.

PS: I know that service is not being called as I have log inside service implementation, so whenever service is consumed I will get a log.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You could check permissions, http content lengths, if the site is started and running the proper app pool for your code, just to name a few trouble shooting steps. Without more information this won't be easy for anyone to answer. You need to be clear on your question.

Comment: Please state what error messages and HTTP status/error codes you are getting on the client that is calling the WCF service.

Comment: @Christoph I tried sending the query string while running the project using POSTMAN, and was able to successfully post the data, where as when I tried to post after I published to IIS, I got error 404.15 - Not found